# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSDictionary'

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2, ios9

I don't know what it means that I need an optional type. I tried to do the Do/ catch but it still doesn't seem to work.

```
do {
    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

    if let parseJSON = json {

        let userId = parseJSON["userId"] as? String
        if (userId != nil) {

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(parseJSON["userFirstName"], forKey: "userFirstName")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(parseJSON["userLastName"], forKey: "userLastName")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(parseJSON["userId"], forKey: "userId")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

            // take user to a protected page
            /*
            let mainPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainPageViewController") as! MainPageViewController

            let mainPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainPage)
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate

            appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = mainPageNav
            */

            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

            appDelegate.buildNavigationDrawer()

        } else {

            // display an alert message
            let userMessage = parseJSON["message"] as? String
            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:nil)
            myAlert.addAction(okAction);
            self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this line, using `as!`:

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
```

you force-cast the result of NSJSONSerialization to an NSDictionary.

So the resulting `json` is not an Optional: you don't have to unwrap it with `if let`.

Remove the `if let parseJSON = json { }` part and use `json` directly:

```
let userId = json["userId"] as? String
```

etc.

Or if you want to keep the result an Optional, you can use `as?`:

```
if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
    let userId = json["userId"] as? String
    // etc
}
```

Comment: Awesome it works thanks! But question, should I still replace '  let userId = parseJSON["userId"] as? String' to 'let userId = json["userId"] as? String'

Comment: Come on, if you follow the logic of the code you will find the answer yourself. :) I'll post an example if you're lost but really please try it out, adapt, you'll see it's not complex.

Comment: I ran it through it and its not sending anything to the database, and I step through it and it fails on this code do you know what else it could be?